Unions of matchings in a bipartite graph (follow-up)
Let $G$ be a bipartite graph with parts $X$ and $Y$. Let $A\subseteq X$ and $B\subseteq Y$ and assume that there exists matching in $G$ that covers all vertices in $A$ and another matching that covers all vertices in $B$. Show that there is a matching that covers all vertices in $A \cup B$.
I know how to prove it but just some details not that clear. We take union of the two matchings covering $A$ and $B$, the case where one of the connected components in this union is a path of even length is a bit confusing to me.
Now consider a connected component $P$ (in the union of the two matchings), which is a path with an odd number of vertices, hence an even number of edges. Let $x_1, \ldots, x_k$ be the vertices of this path. Suppose without loss of generality that $x_1x_2 \in M_A$. As the edges alternate between $M_A$ and $M_B$, and $k$ is odd, we have $x_{k-1}x_k \in M_B$. This means that $x_k \notin A$, because $x_{k-1}x_k$ is the only edge of $H = M_A \cup M_B$ containing $x_k$, so $x_k$ is not covered by $M_A$. Now add to $M$ the matching $x_1x_2, x_3x_4, \ldots, x_{k-2}x_{k-1}$. This matching covers all vertices of $P \setminus \{x_k\}$.
My question is we only show $x_k$ is not in $A$, then why it also not in $B$?

The way you have written it makes it very confusing. Here is the same thing rephrased:
Since P is an even path, $x_1$ and $x_k$ belong to the same color class of $G$ say $X$. Since $P$ is an even $M_A,M_B$-alternating path, we may assume without loss of generality that $x_1x_2 \in M_A$ and $x_{k-1}x_k \in M_B$. Note that $x_k$ is NOT saturated (or covered as you called it) by $M_A$ so clearly $x_k \notin A$ and you may include into $M$ the edges $P \cap M_A$.
The point you had raised is why we do not argue explicitly that $x_k \notin B$ and that is because of the fact that $x_k \in X$.
